# Is this synonym request truly unanswerable with facts and citations? Does it need to be edited? If so, how?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question

[Term for wavelength-restricted or filtered light having a fairly pure color besides "colored light"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/569766/217285) has been closed with the advice to

> Update the question so it can be answered with facts and citations. This will help others answer the question.

I'm asking for help from the English SE community to help me find a word that can potentially fit here. Maybe "light of a pure color" is as close as there is in English, but maybe there's something better.

But all closing does is block potential answer authors from the opportunity to post.

I can't see how to edit this question as I'm the author and I took some time to do my best in explaining the question. So I'm asking for some advice and feedback;

- Is this question honestly unanswerable with facts and citations?
- How might this question be edited, and does it really need to be edited at all?

Comment: I wouldn't take the automatic close text too literally. People voted to close because they  didn't like it and 'opinion based' was the closest. I will note that the question requires a lot of technical knowledge and familiarity with that area's technical language. Very separately, the word 'colored' is not a problem in general. Certainly within the context of describing a person's race it is very old-fashioned and probably taboo, but in other contexts it is not taboo at all, eg 'Rose colored glasses'.

Comment: @Mitch Thanks for your insight! My concern is that everyone is now prevented from posting an answer because three people *didn't like it.* I think others should have a chance at posting an answer, which is why I'm asking what might be done to remove the current block on answers.

Comment: " prevented from posting an answer because three people didn't like it" yeah that's kinda how it works. But as you can see, the question was reopened because enough people (you me and one other) voted that way. So the process is working (helped along by you meta-question here). and now more answers can come in if people have them.

Comment: "Synonym for X, which doesn't work because Y" questions tend to get closed (usually as opinion based) by people who I assume would use X because they don't see Y as being a good enough reason not to. I'm baffled by this. (I spent time and effort reopening another such question earlier this week and last I checked it got another close vote since then)